# set system setting "use only 2g networks" programatically

Tags: android

how can i force the system to use 2g instead of 3g? there is an option for this in the system settings but i didn't find a function in the android-sdk to set this option!

thx

Answer (score 3):

This isn't part of the public SDK at all — the functionality uses internal telephony APIs, as you can see from the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#r4Q5vzOJY9U/src/com/android/phone/Settings.java&l=95) of the Settings application.

This is a universal setting for the entire device anyway, so surely users wouldn't be best pleased about you breaking their data connectivity by switching back and forth between 2G and 3G anyway.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

if this makes sense or not however depends on the application logic and for what i want to do, it DOES make sens!

Comment: Is there any way of detecting whether the user has this setting enabled or not?

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the source code is broken - does anyone have an update?

Comment: Check out this link https://github.com/dzo/packages_apps_phone/blob/master/src/com/android/phone/Settings.java