# Neighbor cells have -1 for CID and LAC

Tags: android, cell

In Android, I try to get the neighbor cells information. I use the following piece of code

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighborCells = telephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();
if (neighborCells == null) {
    Log.d("cells", "Neighbor cells is null");
} else {
    for (NeighboringCellInfo cell : neighborCells) {
        Log.d("cells", cell.getCid()+"-"+cell.getLac()+" "+(-113+cell.getRssi()*2)+"dB");
    }
}
```

Using logcat, I get the following output

```
D/cells   ( 7668): Neighbor cell: -1--1 -81dB
D/cells   ( 7668): Neighbor cell: -1--1 -113dB
D/cells   ( 7668): Neighbor cell: -1--1 -113dB
```

Do you know why ? Is it related with the hardware ? With another phone, I get always "Neighbor cells is null"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, I needed to enable the option "use only 2G networks". What would be nice is the possibility to enable that option from my application. [It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442396/set-system-setting-use-only-2g-networks-programatically) it is not possible but strange because [this application](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mb.toggle2g.plugin.notification) does it...

Does somebody knows why I have more information with 2G cells than 3G ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if youu are using a CDMA phone or a GSM phone. NeighboringCellInfo only works for a GSM phone since you don't have neighboring towers for CDMA. CDMA has a globally unique network id.

```
    TelephonyManager mManager_;
     mManager_ = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    if(mManager_.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA){

        //CDMA PHONE

    }   

    else if(mManager_.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM){

        //GSM PHONE

    }

    uses permission: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but I'm using a GSM phone